# Concatenate Pandas Dataframes Rows side by side / top and bottom in same time

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, concatenation

I've problem. I want to create a new dataframe from another one. I want to avoid duplicate rows. It mean if there is same mails, I should concatenate them side-by-side otherwise top and bottom. But the problem is I'm getting value indexing error every time.

```
pandas.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

And here is what I did :

```
if not self.data.empty:
    if data_frame_['Email'][0] in self.data['Email'].get_values():
        self.data = pd.concat([self.data, data_frame_], axis=1)
    else:
        self.data = pd.concat([self.data,data_frame_], axis=0)  
else: 
    self.data = data_frame_.copy()

end = time.time()
```

data_frame_ has only one row this is why I'm using

```
data_frame_['Email'][0]
```

Exemple of data (which is in data_frame_ ):

```
 Email                     Project1 Target1 Projetc2 Target2
-------------------------------------------------------------
 kml@mail.com                1      5000     NaN       NaN
 abc@abc.com                 7      5000     NaN       NaN
 kml@mail.com                7      4000     NaN       NaN
```

What I desire is :

```
 Email                     Project1 Target1 Projetc2 Target2
-------------------------------------------------------------
 kml@mail.com               1       5000      7       4000
 abc@abc.com                7       5000     NaN       NaN
```

Ps : I could do it using dicts but to protect code integrity, I'd like to use dataframes.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), but first create groups by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
#rename columns
df.rename(columns={'Project1':'Project','Target1':'Target'}, inplace=True)

print (df)
      Email                Project  Target
0  kml@mail.com              1    5000
1  abc@abc.com               7    5000
2  kml@mail.com              7    4000

df['g'] = (df.groupby('Email').cumcount() + 1).astype(str)

df1 = df.pivot_table(index='Email', columns='g', values=['Project', 'Target'])
#Sort multiindex in columns 
df1 = df1.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
#'reset' multiindex in columns
df1.columns = [''.join(col) for col in df1.columns]
print (df1)
                     Project1  Target1  Project2  Target2
Email                                                    
abc@abc.com               7.0   5000.0       NaN      NaN
kml@mail.com              1.0   5000.0       7.0   4000.0
```

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck! And thank you for accepting!

Comment: I didn't realize it (because there is about 100 columns in my data frame), there is missing columns when I use pivot_table (I tested, after pivot_table operation I lose them). I'm losing 3 column. 2 of them are date values like '2016-07-29' and the third one is a string. I don't understand why, do you have any ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: Yes,  there is problem described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns). `Groupby` and `pivot` is very similar, so I think this is valid for `pivot` too.